# SQL computed column for sum of data in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I have two tables:

```
  DiskUsage Table                               StatisticsTable
Server    DiskUsage(GB)                  Total Disk Usage        xxxx
   1         10
   2         212
   3         11
```

I need to create the "Total Disk Usage" as a column which works out the Sum of the `"DiskUsage"` column. This would need to be dynamic as more servers will be added overtime to the `"DiskUsage"` table.

I've done some looking into this - and I believe a Computed Column would be the easiest way to achieve this, but I'm not sure how to a). reference the other tables data or b). dynamically obtain the total of that column.

Comment: Why don't you use a `View`?

Comment: I'll be using SSRS to generate a executive view - and need to show the total used space against available space on our storage platform.

Comment: I mean that I'd convert the "StatisticsTable" in a View.

Comment: `CREATE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED VIEW StatisticsTable AS SELECT SUM(DiskUsage) as TotalDiskUsage FROM DiskUsageTable;`
Vie is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `trigger`

```
CREATE TRIGGER test
ON DiskUsage
after INSERT, UPDATE
AS
  BEGIN
      UPDATE StatisticsTable
      SET    TotalDiskUsage = (SELECT Sum(DiskUsage)
                               FROM   DiskUsage)
  END
```

Or as Mentioned by King.code create a view instead of having a table

```
CREATE VIEW StatisticsTable
AS
  SELECT Sum(DiskUsage)
  FROM   DiskUsage
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the issue with just running a query?

```
select sum(diskusage)
from diskusage;
```

This seems simple enough and unless you have millions of rows, performance should be quite fast.

Comment: How can I use such a query in SSRS when displaying this value on a graph or chart?